# Restore an entire Google Drive folder

Tags: google-drive, data-recovery

My father-in-law got his computer hi-jacked by Locky Virus Ransomware.
Luckily some of his photos are backed-up in Google Photos.

Is there any way to restore an entire folder or a batch of files to a specific date? Or to write a script to do so?

Comment: How on earth would ransomware affect Google Photos? Regarding Google Drive, unfortunately Google Drive does not have a rollback feature. Dropbox does.

Answer (score 1):

If you access your Google Drive online, you will see an icon with a letter **"i"** in it.

Clicking on this will show you the history of everything that has happened within that folder you are in. Go check the dates prior to the date the folders got hacked. I cannot guarantee that you will see dates of his files being uploaded but it's worth a try.

This is what I did when I lost my saved backup files for my websites. I was able to recover a few but not all.